# Error in infobox(textOutput("state")) : could not find function "infobox"

Tags: r, shiny

I want to show the textOutput in an infobox.
I am getting error:

> Error in infobox(textOutput("state")) : could not find function "infobox".

My code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Bus late time"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("statenames", "select the state", c("b1", "b2","b3"))),
mainPanel(
infobox(textOutput("state"))))))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
output$state <- renderText(input$statenames)
})
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `shinydashboard::infoBox`?

Comment: Yes I want infoBox in shinydashboard.

Answer (score 0):

`infoBox` is part of the `shinydashboard` package. To use it in your UI, you can load `shinydashboard` before defining your UI.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Bus late time"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("statenames", "select the state", c("b1", "b2","b3"))),
    mainPanel(
      infoBox(textOutput("state"))
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$state <- renderText(input$statenames)
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

If you want to dynamically update the contents of your `valueBox`, you might consider using `renderInfoBox/infoBoxOutput` instead of `renderText/txtOutput`.